# HTML & CSS Nav bar error

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a school project where I have to make a navigation bar in HTML & CSS. I have the following code, but it's not as responsive as I'd like it to be.

As I make the screen smaller, the text gets closer together. How would I add a fixed space between the `p` classes or use another way to fix this problem?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Header</title> <!-- This is the page title -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <!-- This adds the stylesheet so that "style.css" can edit this page -->
    <meta content="Hugh Chalmers" name="author"> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header"> <!-- This will be the Navigation Bar part of the page. Currently, it is invisible, but the CSS will change that. -->
        <p class="text" id="home">Home</p>
        <p class="text" id="about">About Us</p>
        <p class="text" id="contact">Contact Us</p>
        <p class="text" id="products">Products</p>
        <p class="text" id="forums">Forums</p>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
.header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: red;
}

.text {
    font-family: font-family: 'PT Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
}

#home {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
}

#about {
    position: absolute;
    left: 15%;
}

#contact {
    position: absolute;
    left: 27%;
}

#products {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
}

#forums {
    position: absolute;
    left: 53%;
}
```

Comment: That's an _awful_ lot of `absolute` positioning-- will become a real bear to maintain as your page grows.  I'd definitely advise considering doing something less manual, where the page can flow your content naturally according to some gentler rules.

Comment: you have real messy css styles

Answer (score 1):

If your navigation bar is supposed to represent a list of options (which, really, is what a navigation bar does), then it makes a lot more sense semantically to use, well, a list. Since the order doesn't really matter, we'd use a unordered list, `<ul>`:

```
<div class="header">
    <ul>
        <li class="text" id="home">Home</li>
        <li class="text" id="about">About Us</li>
        <li class="text" id="contact">Contact Us</li>
        <li class="text" id="products">Products</li>
        <li class="text" id="forums">Forums</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then, to display then horizontally, it's a simple matter of either floating them, or changing the display mode. I prefer the latter:

```
.header ul li
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

An example with a slightly tweaked version of your CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/L0pb47ms/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `position:absolute` to do this, you can use `display:inline-block` on the `p` elements.

```css
.header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: red;
}

.text {
    font-family: font-family: 'PT Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

You don't have to style every individual `p`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cu469jzf/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your CSS styles with these

CSS:

```css
.header {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
.text {
    font-family: font-family: 'PT Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
}
.header p {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .text {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 350;
  }
 .header p {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this, however as the screen size decreases, the list items disappear. How would I fix this?

Comment: you need to  learn about [Media Query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)  I also edited my answer with media query to solve your problem @HughChalmers

Comment: [This](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) is a good resource for specifically finding what size you need to specify, for each device. However, I have almost always just gotten around with one size; it really depends on how your html and css is structured and what positioning, units, etc. you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your html and css styles with these :

```css
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
}

ul.topnav li {float: left;}

ul.topnav li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #111;}
ul.topnav li.right {float: right;}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
    ul.topnav li.right, 
    ul.topnav li {float: none;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```